# Array Bounds cannot appear in type specifiers/ I can't figure it out

Tags: vb.net

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\ACCOUNTS\") = True Then
        Else
        End If


        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            Label1.Text = "Error, More than one character requried."
        Else
        End If

        If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
            Label1.Text = "Error, Please Insert A Password."
        Else
            MkDir("C:\ACCOUNTS\" + TextBox1.Text)
            Dim username As System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\ACCOUNTS\" + TextBox1.Text + "\" + "username.txt")
            username.Write(TextBox1.Text)
            username.close()
            Dim password As System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\ACCOUNTS\" + TextBox1.Text + "\" + "password.txt")
            password.Write(TextBox2.Text)
            password.close()
            Label1.Text = "Account is Verified."
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: There is no question here. Please add a question, details, etc.  And this is not vba, right?

Comment: At last tell us on which line you are getting the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing the `New` keyword in your variable declarations. Without that, you cannot create an instance of a class. For example:

```
Dim username As New System.IO.StreamWriter("...")
'               ^^^
```